# How to change position of bootstrap modal dialog

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to set the modal dialog position lower , I've tried to change so many properties of  bootstrap.css file but no one of that changes  works,what is the property that I have to change and in what class?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Bootstrap Login Form</title>
        <meta name="generator" content="Bootply" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
<!--login modal-->
<div id="loginModal" class="modal show" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
          <h1 class="text-center">Login</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <form class="form col-md-12 center-block">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Sign In</button>
              <span class="pull-right"><a href="#">Register</a></span><span><a href="#">Need help?</a></span>
            </div>
          </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
          <div class="col-md-12">
          <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
          </div>    
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <!-- script references -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 Modal Position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20313798/bootstrap-3-modal-position)

Comment: Maybe this helps too: http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/bootstrap/modal.php - the second example.